# Основная мысль текста

Tags: семантика, лексика

Текст:

"Беспамятный" человек - это прежде всего человек неблагодарный, безответственный и, следовательно, неспособный на добрые, бескорыстные поступки.

Безответственность рождается отсутствием сознания того, что ничто не проходит бесследно. Человек, совершающий недобрый поступок, думает, что поступок этот не сохранится в памяти его личной и в памяти окружающих. Он сам, очевидно, не привык беречь память о прошлом, испытывать чувство благодарности к предкам, к их труду, их заботам и поэтому думает, что и о нем все будет позабыто.

Совесть - это в основном память, к которой присоединяется моральная оценка совершенного. Но если совершенное не сохраняется в памяти, то не может быть и оценки. Без памяти нет и совести.

Основная мысль текста заключена в утверждении:

- А) Безответственность - результат отсутствия памяти.
- Б) Если совершенное не сохраняется в памяти, то нет и оценки.
- В) Без памяти нет и совести.
- Г) Безответственный человек не способен беречь память о прошлом.
- Д) Безответственный человек не способен на бескорыстные поступки.

Какой вариант правильный, по-вашему? И объясните ваш ход мыслей! Потому как, я нахожу тут 3-4 правильных ответа. Может я так глуп? Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не глупы. Вы просто пытаетесь оценить высказывания сами по себе, безотносительно к тексту. Поэтому получается много вариантов. Идите от конкретного текста, от позиции автора. Еще важно помнить, что это текст рассуждение. И здесь четко прослеживается его структура: тезис. основная часть (доказательства), вывод. Что находите в выводе? Правильно, "без памяти нет и совести"

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!) Я этого не знал :) Пойду прогуглю и хорошенько проштудирую структуры типов речи.

Answer (score 2):

В) Без памяти нет и совести

Цепочка рассуждений: "Беспамятный" человек - это прежде всего человек неблагодарный, безответственный и, следовательно, неспособный на добрые, бескорыстные поступки. Автор исходит из того, что безответственность ведёт к неспособности на добрые, бескорыстные поступки,затем - к неблагодарности,затем к отсутствию вообще оценки. А совесть - это и есть нравственная оценка, нравственная ответственность. Значит, он называет совесть  главным качеством человека, а не просто ответственность.

Comment: Согласна с Вами.

Answer (score 2):

Тут нарушена логика, поэтому основную мысль найти сложно.
Беспамятный человек может не помнить зла, например. Безответственность может быть результатом надежды на авось.

Далее: *Человек, совершающий недобрый поступок, думает, что поступок этот не сохранится в памяти его личной и в памяти окружающих. Он сам, очевидно, не привык беречь память о прошлом, испытывать чувство благодарности к предкам, к их труду, их заботам и поэтому думает, что и о нем все будет позабыто.*
В первом предложении — о том, что забудут его плохой поступок, в следующем — потому, что он не помнит хорошее (но плохое-то, значит, помнит). И так далее.

Таким образом, в тексте многотемье. Фраза "Без памяти нет и совести" — вывод, так называемая аналитическая оценка ситуации.